# Part of the selected text is hidden when selecting an option

Tags: html, css

I stumbled upon a curiosity.

I have a `select` box that allows overflow with an option that exceeds the width of the `select` box:

[image]

When I select the `option`, however, part of the text disappears:

[image]

This appears to be related to the `option`'s width. If I increase the `option`'s width, I can select more of the text. However, even if I set it to 100% (of the `select` box), I still can't select all of the text.

[complimentary jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vw3wd2ft/1/)

Is this something obvious to the CSS experts out there?

*After a little more thinking*: `width: 100%` obviously won't work. Am I forced to use JavaScript to dynamically set the width of the options to the max width?

Comment: What browser/version are you testing this on? Looks fine to me on Chrome Version 61.0.3163.79

Comment: Chrome 60.0.3112.113

Comment: @MasterYoda, select text and scroll to the right, I see the issue in Chrome

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Now that you mention it and after checking OP's screenshots i'm seeing it now. Your solution works fine for me. Is this a bug with Chrome you think?

Comment: @MasterYoda, I can't test the fully the same code in another browsers, in Mozilla and Opera I don't see any scrollbars at all with the same code, but after small changes, looks like it only Chrome issue.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Yes, even if you change the value of `overflow` from `auto` to `scroll`, there are still no scrollbars in IE or Edge. Huh

Comment: On opera on chrome I see the problem and it seems that it only the background color that is not updated on the whole text. This is observable by setting the option background-color to another color.

Comment: Likely a cross browser issue / browser quirk. Also, not really best practice to style <option> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float: left` on `option` (tested in Chrome):

```css
select {
  width: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
}

option {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<select size="3">
    <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>    
    <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: display: inline; causes the options to stack horizontally

Comment: @MichaelMcLaughlin, Yes, but it solves the OP's issue and answers His question

Comment: I'm all for answers the OP's specific question, but I think we need to put some consideration into the reason for it... I doubt the OP is making a select just for one option. So while this may technically answer the OP's question, its not really a solution for the actual problem.

Comment: @MichaelMcLaughlin, OP didn't say anything about that He doesn't want to use horizontal options. In provided code it doesn't change anything, just solve the issue.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide huh, this fixed it for the fiddle, but in my actual code, it stacked all of the options horizontally. I'll need to investigate more - not sure why this happened.

Comment: @pushkin, you mean `float: left` solution doesn't work? Try to inspect `select` and `option` elements in your project, may be they have any unexpected styles.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Correct, `float: left` didn't work. I tried that inspecting, and the `float: left` style is being applied.

Comment: @pushkin, I'm not really good in floating, may be any styles of parent elements makes the behavior different...

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I took a look at this again today, and what I discovered is that the moment the `select`'s `width` increases by so much that overflow isn't triggered, `float: left` will stack the options. If you increase your `select`'s width to `60%` for instance, the `select` will break. Might be a Chromium bug... though I'm not super familiar with floating.

Comment: @pushkin, I'm not very familiar with floating too, just know the major behavior. I really like flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

*BEST ITERATION OF FIX AT BOTTOM*

If you are looking for browser consistency it is probably best to use a plugin. I would recommend using a plugin like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

if you are ok with preventing side scrolling you can simply add

`overflow-x: hidden;`

to the select box.

I actually found that if you removed the size attribute from the select tag you were left with a completely different rendering of said tag. Not sure how it happened but you should try it and see if that is a closer version of what you are looking for.

The best fix is probably to add

`overflow: auto;`

to your option tag.

this cutoff is caused by an overflow hidden implicitly on the option tag

Comment: That gets rid of the scrollbar, which is not what I want. Also, this code is only being run in Chromium ([electron](https://electron.atom.io/)), so cross-browser compatibility isn't particularly important to me. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I think its rather extreme to say "you should definitely not use select boxes ever"...

Comment: @FluffyKitten disagree. tables, selects, progress bars, i'll even go as far as checkboxes too. those should just be hidden from the user with a nice ui in front of it provided by any of the n plugins out there

Comment: Now, that is *definitely* extreme. Checkboxes?! Sure they mightn't look pretty, but they work and I'm sure many sites don't need to use additional unnecessary plugins just to make them look nice. There's a lot more to the web pages than looking pretty.

Comment: Also  `overflow-x: hidden;` doesn't do the job either... it just prevents you from scrolling.

Comment: so this is coming from the perspective of browser consistency. i'm sure there's a better post somewhere out there this can be discussed, but i wrote that from the perspective of consistency... which, i would think the OP would care about as well if they expect to ever update their app and by association, their version of electron as well. But I'm just presenting one way of solving the problem. I could have withheld the comment about browser implementations. I saw it. thanks. false positive

Comment: Maybe you should update your answer to say you're only taking about browser consistency - it's misleading to say they should never be used because that's just not true.

Comment: @MichaelMcLaughlin `overflow: auto` doesn't work for me, because it adds the scrollbar to the individual option, which is not what I want. I should have clarified in my question that I actually have more than 1 option.